# Question about RPM in Fedora

Tags: fedora, rpm

I want to make install file in Fedora.

(Download files from Internet and save it in specific directory. Path is fixed)

Someone suggest me to use rpm file, so I found some document.

According to my knowledge, RPM contains download source file and **'BUILD'**  operation and so on.

What I want to do is just download file, so BUILD operation is not needed.

So I can't sure making RPM is suitable for my job.

There is some way 'just download file' in RPM or I should change my way.

I want your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do these help ?

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&noj=1&biw=1280&bih=841&q=how+to+create+rpm+&oq=how+to+create+rpm+&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=605090l617014l0l617629l48l43l13l12l22l1l743l5182l5.3.2.0.5.2.1l18l0

Comment: I already read first link but it contains build process, too. And I will reference second link thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Which rpm file do you want to download ?

After downloading you can install like this =>

```
rpm -ivh file.rpm
```

Which fedora do you use ? fedora 15 ?

You can download from here =>

http://fedora.zero42.at/linux/releases/15/Fedora/i386/os/Packages/

Comment: I use Fedora 15 and my question is how to make rpm file just download file form internet. Not how to download rpm file from internet